# Text Immediately vanishes

Tags: vb.net

I'm trying to display some text results in a groupbox.  My printing subs generally follow this format (Picture_Text is a groupbox):

```
Sub pr_mg_c(ByRef var As Object, ByRef position As Single)
    Dim g As Graphics = Picture_text.CreateGraphics
    g.DrawString(var, ScreenFont, Brushes.Black, coord)
    g.Dispose()
End Sub
```

When I try to display the results, the entirety of the text pops up in the control and immediately disappears.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Draw and Paint in the Paint event and do not use `CreateGraphics` and turn on `Option Strict`  Also please read [ask] and take the [tour]

Comment: Much appreciated.

Comment: It also makes no sense that those parameters are declared `ByRef`.  You should do some reading and learn what that is actually for.

Comment: `CreateGraphics` is almost always the wrong thing to do.  I've done graphics work in C# regularly since the 1.0 framework was released, and I've *never* had to actually use it.  Props for disposing of the result though, but try `Using` next time, it's better.

Comment: You might also want to consider using `TextRenderer.DrawText`